# Generate events with given probability.

Tags: probability-theory

Assume that we have events $X = {\{x_i\}}_{i=1}^n$ with given probabilities $p_i$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=1$. And uniform random number generator $RND$, which can generate numbers in $[0, 1]$ segment.

We need to generate approximately $M$ events from $X$ so that their probabilities will be the same as given above.

I know two approaches:

**First:**

For each event $x_i$ generate random number $p'$ using $RND$, if $p' \le p_i$
 than yield $x_i$. Repeat until $M$ events collected.

**Second:**

- Sort $x_i$ in ascending order according to its probability.
- Renumber $x_i$ so that $p_{i-1} \le p_i$.
- For each $x_i$ evaluate $g_i = \sum_{k=1}^i p_k$.
- Generate random number $p'$ using $RND$. Find $g_i$, such that $p' \in (g_{i-1}; g_i]$ and yield $x_i$.
- Repeat previous step until $M$ events collected.

Do this approaches give the same results?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about your first approach? How do you repeat until M events are obtained?

Comment: @StefanHansen Pass through all events, if I passed all events and number of collected events is less then $M$ then I pass through all events again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving efficiency aside, the first approach has the problem that  you (normally) want that the succesive events to be independent, but your fixed visiting schedule (that is, you try each event in a fixed cyclic manner) imposes a dependence. For example, if you have 2 equiprobable events {A,B}, then if a the event A has just happened, the probability that after it there comes a B is greater than 1/2. This can be fixed by imposing a random visiting strategy. That is, you first select the event index at random (uniformly in $1 \cdots n$).